# Trying to interface Oled display with MLX90614 IR Sensor

Tags: c

Hi i am working on a school project where I'm supposed to output temperature values on an Oled display.

i have managed to do it with Arduino Code so i know that the sensor and display works, but the code has to be written in Atmel studio in pure embedded C for the project.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and what I'm am doing right.
I'm struggling with C code and the I2C protocol.

i have done a lot of research on the subject but evertime i seem to only find arduino tutorials, or theory related posts.

I'm totally new to programming.

anyway this is the code i have come up with so far.

the txt i have written for the display is displayed. everthing works as it should except for the temperatur values:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "OLED.h"
#include "ATmega_Init.h"
#include "i2c_master.h"

//From Arduino Adafruit_MLX90614 lib
// RAM
#define MLX90614_RAWIR1 0x04
#define MLX90614_RAWIR2 0x05        //Important for reading out
#define MLX90614_TA 0x06
#define MLX90614_TOBJ1 0x07
#define MLX90614_TOBJ2 0x08

// EEPROM
#define MLX90614_TOMAX 0x20
#define MLX90614_TOMIN 0x21
#define MLX90614_PWMCTRL 0x22
#define MLX90614_TARANGE 0x23
#define MLX90614_EMISS 0x24
#define MLX90614_CONFIG 0x25
#define MLX90614_ADDR 0x0E
#define MLX90614_ID1 0x3C
#define MLX90614_ID2 0x3D
#define MLX90614_ID3 0x3E
#define MLX90614_ID4 0x3F

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x5A



int main(void)
{

    //uint8_t test_recieve[2];

    uint16_t test_recieve_high;     //To receive the high byte

    uint16_t test_recieve_low;      //To receive the low byte


    init_atmega_setup();

    initDisplay();

    i2c_init();

    clsDisplay();

    strFont5XY("Floor Unit",25,3);

    _delay_ms(2000);

    clsDisplay();

    //uint8_t receive_command = 0x00;   //Needs the receive command, 
    definitely not just 0x00

        while(1){

            i2c_start(SLAVE_ADDRESS);

            i2c_write(MLX90614_TOBJ1);

            i2c_start(SLAVE_ADDRESS);

            test_recieve_high = i2c_read_ack();

            i2c_start(MLX90614_TOBJ1);

            test_recieve_high = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8;

            test_recieve_high |= i2c_read_ack();

            i2c_stop();


            i2c_start(SLAVE_ADDRESS);

            i2c_write(MLX90614_TOBJ1);*/

            i2c_start(MLX90614_TOBJ1);

            test_recieve_low = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8;

            test_recieve_low |= i2c_read_ack();

            i2c_stop();

            intFont5XY(test_recieve_low,1,0);

            intFont5XY(test_recieve_high,1,1);

            _delay_ms(1000);
        };
    };
```

Comment: "everthing works as it should except for the temperatur values" What temperature values? Where are they and what isn't working? Also if everything else works, what makes you think this is related to I2C and not some algorithm?

Comment: the temperature values are suppose to be read from the sensor and then outputtet to the display.

i think it is the I2C connection + my lack of programming skills which is the problem. 

the reason i think that the problem is related to the i2c connection. is that i can output any text i want. but i cant collect the data from the sensor to output on the display.